# Performance impact of lookbehinds and lookaheads in regular expressions

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, lookbehind

I came across this question earlier today [Catastrophic backtracking issue with large string using regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51590024).

On Wiktor Stribiżews answer it's explained very intuitively why the lazy pattern of the OP [(OP regex, 317 steps)](https://regex101.com/r/hBK9Lb/1) is not appropiate for long strings and hence is failing, suggesting a [new regex, 46 steps](https://regex101.com/r/hBK9Lb/2).

Now, OP wanted to match a text between known tags. It looks for me that this is the perfect, most obvious usage of lookahead and lookbehind, since you are literally looking for something between two known strings, and as such made [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/Dskl2s/1/). It comes out with 131 steps. It is not as bad as OPs, but it is far behind 46.

I would've thought that the lookbehind is sought for, and once found it matches everything while looking for the lookahead, but given those 131 steps this doesn't seem to be the case.

How lookaheads and lookbehinds work in terms of performance? I've found some documentation on this ([1](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) , [2](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html)) but I'm not finding the information on how they work internally or the performance implications of using them.

Comment: From my practical experience, regex flavors differ even in this aspect. You can't make this question language agnostic. Well, it is a rather broad topic.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks for the heads up on flavors. For the common pcre and python it gives 131 steps on both so (taking a big guess here) they may have the same internals regarding this. The issue is it's apparently very hard to find documentation on this :/

Comment: @Jorge.V you should compare `(?<=<CSVIntervalData>).*(?=<\/CSVIntervalData>)` to `<CSVIntervalData>.*<\/CSVIntervalData>` if you are interested in the performance impact of the lookarounds. You will notice that the lookaround pattern needs an additional step per backtrack to .. recognize.. the lookaround.

Comment: Wiktors pattern on the other hand is all about chunk wise matching with clear cut borders, it would even work as `NEM12[^<]*(?:<[^<]*)*?</CSVIntervalData>` and outperform any `.*` approach. Note that the regex engine internally optimizes `[^<]*` to `[^<]*+`.

Comment: @SebastianProske Thanks for your comment. Yeah, I understand Wiktors "smart" approach, I just don't get why removing the lookarounds as you did reduces the execution from 131 to 55 steps; in other words: Why it takes extra steps to "recognise" the lookaround, why this is the case and on what it depends, so that I can have an OK situation for lookarounds and a No-way one. It'd be nice if someone knew how the internals work, or a source for the related documentation.